# Pass future method values to next insert

Tags: apex, future

I am creating a case in Public method. And I need to access its Id in Future method. How do I do that. I am unable to fetch the record Id.

In Public method a case is created.In future method I am creating some more cases based on some condition. Now for Every case that is created in Future method, I need to create a related case and assign the First case ID (Case that was created in Public method) in Related case field of that case.

In Public method I have written below code that calls future method.

```
if(clist.size()>0)
{        
    string jsonString = JSON.serializePretty(clist);
    caseinsert(jsonString);
}
```

Future Method code.

```
@future public static void caseinsert(string caselist)
{
    List<Related_Case__c> Rclist1=new List<Related_Case__c>();
    list<case> insertAccList =  (list<case>)JSON.deserializeStrict(caselist, list<case>.class);

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(insertAccList); 
    for(database.saveresult db:results)
    {
        Related_Case__c rc = new Related_Case__c();
        rc.Case__c=db.getid();
        //rc.Related_Case__c=ROcase.Id;
        Rclist1.add(rc);
    }

    IF(Rclist1.size()>0)
    {
        Database.SaveResult[] results2=Database.insert(Rclist1);
    }

}
```

`rc.Related_Case__c` is Required field and does not allow to insert the record if no value is given.

ROcase is the case that is created in Public method.

Comment: why don't you pass this Id in parameter.

Comment: @TusharSharma If you are asking about the Future method parameter, then the String that is passed as parameter is a list of cases that need to be created.

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more context to be able to be of help. I don't see `ROcase` defined anywhere, and your description so far makes me think that `ROcase` is exactly the same as the `Cases` that you're passing to your `@future` method.

Comment: If you have a list of Id's for the parent cases, you can pass them to your future method as a list of strings. You can also query for them if you have sufficient info in what you've sent in the jason string.

Comment: Just in case it helps, do keep in mind that an `@future` method is a completely separate transaction from the one that is running your public method (i.e. the one that is calling your `@future` method). The only data that your future method has access to is the data that you pass to your `@future` method (and anything that you can query from within your `@future` method).

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your reply. @DerekF ROcase is defined in Public method.  To be more clear-- First ROcase is created. Then some more cases are created and inserted through clist (Which is done in future method). Then for all the cases that are inserted through future method, we need to create a Related case and That case should contain the ROcase in rc.Related_Case__c field. Now the Problem is I am unable to fetch the ROcase Id.  The List of Strings that I have passed in Future method is clist(Second set of cases to be created) not ROcase.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't access `ROCase.Id` in your `@future` method is because you're not passing that information to your `@future` method.

As I said in the comments, an `@future` method runs in a completely separate transaction from the code that calls the `@future` method. The only data that an `@future` method has is the data that you pass to it, and the data that you create or query (directly or indirectly) as part of the `@future` method.

The simplest solution to your problem would be to reconsider if you really need to create and insert your `Related_Case__c` records in a separate transaction. Using `@future` adds to the complexity of a solution, and is best avoided if possible.

If you really do need to use `@future`, then you need to modify your `@future` method signature to accept an additional argument. Something like

```
@future public static void caseinsert(string caselist, Id firstCaseId)
```

I hope it goes without saying that by adding an additional parameter, you'll also need to change the code that calls your `@future` method to pass the additional argument.

Comment: Hi @Derek Thanks for the Information. I will look into it.